# Como Transformo meus resultados em arquivo txt, excel ou word?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, impressão, txt, microsoft-word

tenho um código em Python que faz o seguinte: Extrai vários dados de tabelas em excels distintos e realiza uma regressão linear entre eles. Até aí tudo bem mas como faço meus resultados saírem limpos em um arquivo TXT, excel ou word? Obrigado

Segue meu código simplificado pois há bem mais dados:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly as py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# Carrega a taxa de cambio em Dólares por Real
CAMBIO = pd.read_csv("CAMBIO.csv", parse_dates=["DATE"], index_col="DATE", na_values=".")
CAMBIO['USREAL'] = pd.to_numeric(CAMBIO['USREAL'])
CAMBIO['USREAL'] = CAMBIO.USREAL.shift().apply(np.log) - pd.to_numeric(CAMBIO['USREAL']).apply(np.log)
CAMBIO.columns = ["ReturnsCAMBIO"]
CAMBIO = CAMBIO.asfreq('B')
CAMBIO = CAMBIO.reset_index()


# INICIO DA SEQUENCIA de REGRESSOES

#REGRESSAO DE BBAS3
BBAS3 = pd.read_csv("BBAS3.csv", parse_dates=["Date"], index_col="Date", 
na_values="null")
BBAS3.drop(["Open", "High", "Low", "Adj Close", "Volume"], axis=1, inplace=True)
BBAS3['Close'] = BBAS3.Close.shift().apply(np.log) - 
pd.to_numeric(BBAS3['Close']).apply(np.log)
BBAS3 = BBAS3.interpolate()
BBAS3.columns = ["ReturnsBBAS3"]
BBAS3 = BBAS3.asfreq('B')
BBAS3 = BBAS3.reset_index()
BBAS3 = BBAS3.dropna(axis=0, how='any')


#CONCATENAMOS NA MATRIZ SENSIBILIDADE BBAS3
sensitivityBBAS3 = pd.concat([CAMBIO, BBAS3], axis=1)
sensitivityBBAS3 = sensitivityBBAS3.dropna(axis=0, how='any')

#REALIZAMOS A REGRESSAO COM TODOS FATORES BBAS3
y = sensitivityBBAS3['ReturnsBBAS3']
X = sensitivityBBAS3[["ReturnsCAMBIO"]]
RegressionBBAS3 = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(RegressionBBAS3.summary())
```

Queria que esse sumamary de RegressionBBAS3 fosse exportado para txt ou excel ou word.

Comment: Mostre a saída de RegressionBBAS3 pra ver como está os dados, enfim com dica (pois não tenho como testar) tente criar um DataFrame com essa saída e depois exportar para Excel usando o Pandas. Exemplo: Criar DataFrame `planilha_final = pd.DataFrame(RegressionBBAS3)` | Salvar em Excel `planilha_final.to_excel('planilha_pandas.xlsx', index=False)` espero que algo disse que falei te ajude!

Answer (score 1):

Para criar um ficheiro existe a função [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
file = open("file.txt","w") 
file.write(RegressionBBAS3.summary())
file.close()
```